Project from view does not match with camera's aspect ratio
I am currently working on a project where I need to remove certain object via texture paint. For which I need to use 2 UV maps (UVMap, Project). One is a simple unwrap (UVMap), another need to be projected from view (Project). One other thing to mention is that the project is motion tracked with 0.78px Solve error.
UV unwrap (UVMap) is working fine but the project from view is unwrapping the UV (Project) incorrectly.
As far as I know, if the render image and the texture matches the UV map should match too. But here my render size is 1080x1920 and the texture is also 1080x1920. Yet the project from view is not matching.

As you can see, the vertex on the top right should be in frame along with few other vertices. Here by saying in frame I mean inside the texture. But it's not matching the proportions even though the image size is same for both the render(camera) and the texture.
Now, things that I tried but didn't work are Applying scale for the plane, Project From View(Bounds)


I usually Project from View through the Camera when keeping it to the size of the image source in Render properties. Are you Projecting from view there in the right through the camera? What does the projection look like in the UV Editor? That window on the left is useless as a reference to the unwrap as your camera is the bounds of the image in the UV Editor, if that makes sense.

Below I gave my answer how it usually works. I don't know how the motion tracking is influencing this though. You say "the project" is motion tracked. Since you are writing a lot about projection mapping, do you mean the UVs with "the project"? Or is your object/your scene "the project"? The thing is, when your object is moving, then the UV map created with Project from View of course only matches the position of the plane in camera at the frame when the UVs were projected.

The important thing here is the order of operations when you do the unwrapping. For example, by default the UV Editor shows a square area when there is no image texture.
If the camera's aspect ratio would now be 1:1 and you unwrap with Project from View, the UVs would fit into the square UV space like the object in the square camera view:

Now I switch the aspect ratio of the output to 1:2, notice how the camera view changes its output ratio, but the UVs are still the same projected onto the suqare UV space like before. Of course they did not change because they were not unwrapped again:

Even if you now open an image with the correct aspect ratio in the UV Editor, the UVs are still matched to the original 1:1 aspect ratio and therefore camera view and UV space are not matching:

If you would now unwrap again with Project from View, this should give the correct result. Basically it is best practice to have both, the output aspect ratio and the image texture ratio in the UV Editor the same before doing any unwrapping. If this was the order of operations in your case, then it is hard to say what else could be the problem and we might need your file to check it out.
If I take your screenshot and make a square overlay on the UV map, you can see that the distribution of faces from left to right matches the camera view, although vertically they are still mismatching. I can only assume you have been switching aspect ratios and/or view, texture or whatever. That is the only thing I can see without inspecting your file or knowing the exact steps you took to get there.

Now I see what your problem is - it did not struck my eye in the question's screenshot. You have changed your camera's Sensor Fit to Horizontal instead of the default Auto, why on Earth you did that I do not know because for normal rendering it does not really matter.

In case you really need this, okay - if not and you are not sure I will quickly show what it does.
I will not talk about the given sensor's Size in milimeters here, because this mainly influences the camera's field of view in relation to the focal length but is not important for the different Sensor Fit settings or what impact they have on your Project from View.
So the default setting is Sensor Fit > Auto. This means, Blender will fit the render either horizontally or vertically into the sensor boundaries, depending on the orientation of the image, if it is a landscape or portrait aspect ratio - no matter what, the largest dimension will always fit the sensor boundaries:

As you can see, the cube stays exactly the same within a square area. This represents the view angle of the camera with the given Focal Length and the sensor's Size, in case of Auto a single value which marks the larger dimension, the square indicates the camera can be held either horizontal or vertical. Changing the render output dimensions will result in either cropping top and bottom of the square for a landscape image or cropping left and right for a portrait image.
However changing the Sensor Fit to Horizontal instead of Auto now means, the render output always has to fit inside the width of the sensor boundaries, no matter if it is a landscape or portrait aspect ratio:

With this setting and a typical sensor size of 3:2 in landscape orientation, the cube will be quite large in a landscape render, but become small in a portrait render. The cube keeps the same width compared to the width of the render, but the vertical orientation adds a lot to the top and bottom. Something similar happens when you set the Sensor Fit to Vertical, only that the render now has to fit vertically.
Now why does this affect the Project from View unwrapping? Because by default the Project from View works basically like the Auto fit and uses a square area where the camera view and the UV map is fit into with its largest dimension.
Usually I would say, use the camera with the default Sensor Fit > Auto to avoid these problems, but in case of the existing scene you will get another issue: switching from Horizontal to Auto now produces a completely different field of view - but if I overlay the UVs now with a square like I did earlier and you compare it to the square sensor boundaires on the right, I guess you can see how this happened. As I said, the Project from View works by always taking the larger dimension of the view for the size of the square it projects to:

But do not worry: you do not have to realign your camera again to get the viewing angle like before. You just do not switch to Auto this time. Unwrap the plane again with Project from View, and after unwrapping, switch the options on the bottom left of the viewport from the default Camera Bounds to Correct Aspect and everything looks like it is supposed to be
Default option Camera Bounds:

Changing the option to Correct Aspect:


I'm new to UV Maps and such, so I thought the issue might be with me not tracking the footage correctly. Since that is not the case I'll remove the footage from the file and upload it. I tweaked few things after the screenshot was taken. Added link to blend file.

@Mahir Sorry I didn't have time to look at your file earlier. There was something already in your question's screenshot which slipped my attention, the camera's sensor overlay showing in the viewport. Now that I saw this the solution to your problem was obvious to me, I added it at the end of my answer.

I motion tracked a footage which was vertical. So Blender automatically changed the Sensor Fit.
